# WinForm Button Event Handler (Dynamic)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, eventhandler

I'd like to distinguish each of the Event handler.

(I have only one in my code below. I mean dynamic handler will be the best but, any kind of workarounds will be fine too.)

Please help me.

Thanks !

```
    List<Button> VuttonList = new List<Button>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Vutton;
        int Kount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < Kount ; i++)
        {
            Vutton = new Button();
            Vutton.Text = ( i + 1 ).ToString() ;
            Vutton.Location = new Point(10, 24 * ( i + 1 ) ); 
            Controls.Add( Vutton );
            Vutton.Click    += new EventHandler(Kommon);
            VuttonList.Add( Vutton );
        }
    }

    private void Kommon(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(  sender.ToString() );
    }
```

Comment: One event handler is enough, you can cast the sender to `Button` and this way you know which button has been clicked. Also you can set `Name` property of buttons when you create them or assign `Tag` property of them an use it later.

Comment: The only unique identity you gave the button's are the Text and Location properties, so those you would have to find in your list.  You could also use the Name property, too, and maybe use a Dictionary instead of a List.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for your comment. But, I DO need to distinguish, that is the point of my question.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks. Hmmmm.. that should be good tip. I'll try it out.

Comment: @LarsTech How can I distinguish the name of it ? Like this ? "MessageBox.Show(  sender.Name  );" <-- it is not working, just tried.

Comment: @RezaAghaei This and that.....

Comment: @LarsTech I added "Vutton.Name = i.ToString();"

Comment: @LarsTech "MessageBox.Show( (Button) sender.Name );" ? or something else ? I am not good at C#.

Comment: @Jason *But, I DO need to distinguish* You can simply distinguish using `Name` property, also you have `Tag` and you can use it for additional information.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Tag...Hmmm. OK that sounds good too. Thanks.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Just clicked the "up arrow". I have thought it is a just arrow (I pressed it again and it disappeared, so I pressed again. Now looks good again) Bye.

Comment: I have thought it is a just arrow! :)) ;) Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One event handler is enough, you can cast the sender to `Button` and this way you know which button has been clicked. Also you can set `Name` property of buttons when you create them or assign `Tag` property of them and use it later.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Kount ; i++)
{
    Vutton = new Button();
    //...set properties
    //Also add Name:
    Vutton.Name = string.Format("Vutton{0}", i);
    //Also you can add Tag
    Vutton.Tag = i;
    Controls.Add( Vutton );
    Vutton.Click += new EventHandler(Kommon);
    //... other stuff
}
```

Then you can use properties of button this way:

```
private void Kommon(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    //You can use button.Name or (int)button.Tag and ...
    MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
}
```

Also to layout your buttons, you can use a `FlowLayoutPanel` or a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Oh. Good. Works fine.

Comment: So, that is why you said. One event handler is good enough. Now I got it. Thanks. very. much.

Comment: panle info. That should be another good info. I did not know that even they are existed. Thanks again.